# Unexpected error in php code

Tags: php

PHP newbie. Keep getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

with my code.

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.dcaccountancyservices.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&tmpl=component&chronoform=EditClient&token='  echo $client['id']);
?>
```

Cannot figure out what the syntax error is. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code so that easy to find error.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a programming question per-se. For example search before ask: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Parse+error%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+T_ECHO  - And take a look to the right, the **Related** column.

Comment: Also please take a look at this reference question, you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Answer (score 2):

At the very end of your line, you have:

```
echo $client['id']);
```

You're trying to append the `$client['id']` to the URL, so remove the `echo` and replace it with `.`:

```
header('Location: http://www.dcaccountancyservices.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&tmpl=component&chronoform=EditClient&token=' . $client['id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate the values:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.dcaccountancyservices.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&tmpl=component&chronoform=EditClient&token='  . $client['id']);
```

Comment: I'd say if the error message is too complicated for the OP, there is a problem with your answer because the code-example needs scrolling. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.dcaccountancyservices.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&tmpl=component&chronoform=EditClient&token='.$client['id']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: http://www.dcaccountancyservices.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&tmpl=component&chronoform=EditClient&token='.$client['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not use `echo` when you want to concatenate a string, you use `.` (dot).  So change the your `header` line  to:

```
header('Location: http://www.dcaccountancyservices.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&tmpl=component&chronoform=EditClient&token='.$client['id']);
```